Sum values double counted
I need help with a T-SQL query where I'm adding two columns together. The problem is my code does add them together but then double counts. I've searched around for similar queries but haven't found anything that relates well enough to this query. Here is my code:
SELECT DISTINCT t.Reference, 
u.FileID, 
u.UnpaidVAT, 
u.UnpaidFees, 
CAST(
SUM(u.UnpaidVAT+u.UnpaidFees) 
AS 
DECIMAL(8,2)) AS TotalOutstanding
FROM UnpaidFees u
LEFT JOIN Trans T ON u.Reference=t.InvoiceID
INNER JOIN Matters m ON u.FileId=m.FileId
WHERE t.Narration LIKE 'Invoice'
AND (u.UnpaidVAT>0 OR u.UnpaidFees>0)
AND m.Status=1
GROUP BY t.Reference, u.matterID, u.UnpaidVAT,u.UnpaidFees
;




Reference
FileID
UnpaidVAT
UnpaidFees
TotalOutstanding




1
20
20.00
100.00
240.00


2
21
50.00
250.00
600.00


3
21
12.00
60.00
144.00


4
22
20.00
100.00
240.00



Here you can see the results of my current query, Unpaid VAT and Unpaid Fees have been duplicate counted.
Also, t.InvoiceID, t.Narration, t.Reference and u.FileID will have duplicates entries in their respective tables.
Sample data from Trans table: 



InvoiceID
Narration
Reference




1
Invoice
INV1


1
Fee
INV1


2
Invoice
INV2


2
Fee
INV2


3
Invoice
INV3


3
Fee
INV3


4
Invoice
INV4


4
Fee
INV4




Sample data from UnpaidFees table: 



FileID
Fees
VAT
Reference




20
100.00
20.00
1


21
250.00
50.00
2


22
20.00
100.00
3


22
10.00
50.00
4




Sample data from Matters table: 



FileID
Status




20
1


21
1


22
1


23
0




Where am I going wrong?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question. Sample data is far better served as DDL and DML statements, and expect results as a markdown table.

A DISTINCT with a GROUP BY is always a sign of a flaw in your query. A GROUP BY already causes your data to be returned in distinct sets, so if you are getting duplicates, it likely means your GROUP BY is wrong. Otherwise the DISTINCT is redundant and unneeded overhead.

Why do you LEFT JOIN to Trans when you require a row to be found in the table due to your WHERE? When would you expect t.Narration LIKE 'Invoice' to resolve to TRUE when there was no row found in the table aliased as T?

Share some sample data from each of the three tables (as text). There are a few issues with the query as Thom A pointed out but I suspect a bad join (not joining by enough columns) might be the cause but without seeing any data it's impossible to know.

@AlanSchofield Thanks, I have added some sample data

The Unpaidfees table does not match your query, assuming fees and vat should be UnpaidFees and UnpaidVAT then MatterID is missing. Check your sample data and make sure the column names match the query

I just noticed your query has an error in the grouping, it references u.matterID but your select uses i.FileID. Assuming this was an error, I change the grouping to match the select and when I run with sample data, I do not get duplicates. Here is a fiddle using your sample data and modified query . Note there are still potential issues with the query, but please provide more data to replicate the issue first . Link to SQL Fiddle

I'm sorry, I didn't have time to look closely, but I wouldn't think you need to sum columns that you are already grouping by.  I suspect you have duplicate rows in one of your joins: u.Reference=t.InvoiceID or u.FileId=m.FileId. One of those is returning more than one record per join.
Maybe another column is needed to uniquely make one or both of the joins.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
